# Adding Wordpress Meta boxes

Tags: php, wordpress

I am adding two custom metaboxes to the WordPress post page from a plugin. I am currently doing it with two separate instances of `add_meta_boxes` but this feels very bulky, especially as I go to add more.

Since the plugin is fairly small I dont want to include a framework and was wondering if there was an easier to add more than one metabox. Preferably under one heading, unlike currently if you add this to your `functions.php` or look at the screenshot below, they are under separate headings.

I was considering posting this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com, but as it is working fully I posted it here.

```
function wp_cat_map_add_meta_box() {

$screens = array( 'post' );

foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {
    add_meta_box( 'map_lat', __( 'Add Latitude', 'wp_cat_map' ), 'wp_cat_map_lat_callback', $screen );
    add_meta_box( 'map_long', __( 'Add Longitude', 'wp_cat_map' ), 'wp_cat_map_long_callback', $screen );

}
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wp_cat_map_add_meta_box' );

function wp_cat_map_lat_callback( $post ) {

wp_nonce_field( 'wp_cat_map_lat_data', 'wp_cat_map_lat_nonce' );

$value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_cat_map_lat', true );

echo '<label for="wp_cat_map_lat">';
_e( 'Latitude', 'wp_cat_map' );
echo '</label> ';
echo '<input type="text" id="wp_cat_map_lat" name="wp_cat_map_lat" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '"/>';
}

function wp_cat_map_lat_data( $post_id ) {

if ( ! isset( $_POST['wp_cat_map_lat_nonce'] ) ) {
    return;
}

if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['wp_cat_map_lat_nonce'], 'wp_cat_map_lat_data' ) ) {
    return;
}

if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
    return;
}

if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

} else {

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }
}

if ( ! isset( $_POST['wp_cat_map_lat'] ) ) {
    return;
}

$my_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['wp_cat_map_lat'] );

update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_cat_map_lat', $my_data );
}

function wp_cat_map_long_callback( $post ) {

wp_nonce_field( 'wp_cat_map_long_data', 'wp_cat_map_long_nonce' );

$value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_cat_map_long', true );

echo '<label for="wp_cat_map_long">';
_e( 'Longitude', 'wp_cat_map' );
echo '</label> ';
echo '<input type="text" id="wp_cat_map_long" name="wp_cat_map_long" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '"/>';
}

function wp_cat_map_long_data( $post_id ) {

if ( ! isset( $_POST['wp_cat_map_long_nonce'] ) ) {
    return;
}

if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['wp_cat_map_long_nonce'], 'wp_cat_map_long_data' ) ) {
    return;
}

if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
    return;
}

if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

} else {

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }
}

if ( ! isset( $_POST['wp_cat_map_long'] ) ) {
    return;
}

$my_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['wp_cat_map_long'] );

update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_cat_map_long', $my_data );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'wp_cat_map_lat_data' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'wp_cat_map_long_data' );
```

[image: custom metaboxes]

Answer (score 2):

First thing that pops in the eye is the unindented code, most [IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ide/info)s do this automatically for us. That's fundamental for everyone's sanity, yours and whomever reads your code.

And you are missing two things from [`add_meta_box()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) parameters that will make the code reusable:

```
add_meta_box( $id, $title,$callback, $screen, $context, $priority, $callback_args );
```

One is that `$screen` can be an array, so the `foreach $screens` is unnecessary. And the other is the normally forgotten `$callback_args`, with it we can prepare an array that will build all our metaboxes using the same `$callback` function.

**Notes:**

- `$metaboxes` is the reusable source, just add another item and a new metabox is created.
- `save_post` receives 2 arguments, `$post_id` and `$post_object`.
- I prefer to put all hook declarations at the beginning, as it gives a general panorama of all functions below.
- Use of [`printf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) to build complex HTML blocks.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wp_cat_map_add_meta_box' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'wp_cat_map_data', 10, 2 );

function wp_cat_map_add_meta_box() {
    /* Our configuration vars */
    $screens = array( 'post', 'page' );
    $metaboxes = array(
        'map_lat' => array(
            'label' => 'wp_cat_map_lat',
            'title' => __( 'Add Latitude', 'wp_cat_map' ),
            'description' => __( 'Latitude', 'wp_cat_map' ),
            'name' => 'wp_cat_map_lat',
            'post_meta' => '_wp_cat_map_lat'
        ),
        'map_long' => array(
            'label' => 'wp_cat_map_long',
            'title' => __( 'Add Longitude', 'wp_cat_map' ),
            'description' => __( 'Longitude', 'wp_cat_map' ),
            'name' => 'wp_cat_map_long' ,
            'post_meta' => '_wp_cat_map_long'           
        )
    );
    foreach ( $metaboxes as $meta_id => $meta_cont ) {
        add_meta_box( 
            $meta_id, 
            $meta_cont['title'], 
            'wp_cat_map_callback', 
            $screens, 
            'advanced', 
            'default', 
            $meta_cont 
        );
    }
}

function wp_cat_map_callback( $post, $post_object ) {
    /* Inspect the object */
    // printf( '<pre><code>%s</code></pre>', print_r( $post_object, true ) );
    wp_nonce_field( 'wp_cat_map_data', 'wp_cat_map_nonce' );
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $post_object['args']['post_meta'], true );
    printf( 
        '<label for="%s">%s</label>',
        $post_object['args']['label'],
        $post_object['args']['description'];
    );
    printf(
        '<input type="text" id="%s" name="%s" value="%s"/>',
        $post_object['args']['label'],
        $post_object['args']['post_meta'],
        esc_attr( $value )
    );
}

function wp_cat_map_data( $post_id, $post_object ) { /* code */ }
```

---

**Issue:**
We need those meta names to use in the `save_post` callback. Instead of creating a global variable, it's preferable to create a class to encapsulate everything. This way we can send Screens and Meta Boxes when instantiating the class and have `post_meta` names available inside the `save_post` callback.

```
Class Code_Review_111019 {
    /* Class properties, available to all methods */
    private $screens;
    private $metaboxes;
    
    public function __construct( $screens, $metaboxes ) {
        /* Set properties when instantiating */
        $this->screens = $screens;
        $this->metaboxes = $metaboxes;
        /* Start our hooks at a safer point */
        add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'start_up' ) );
    }
    
    public function start_up() {
        /* Inside classes we don't need unique prefixes or names for the callbacks, better yet, they can be literal */
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_meta_boxes' ) );
        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_post' ), 10, 2 );        
    }
    
    public function add_meta_boxes() {
        foreach ( $this->metaboxes as $meta_id => $meta_cont ) {
            add_meta_box( 
                $meta_id, 
                $meta_cont['title'], 
                array( $this, 'build_metabox' ), 
                $this->screens, 
                'advanced', 
                'default', 
                $meta_cont 
            );
        }
    }

    public function build_metabox( $post, $post_object ) {
        wp_nonce_field( 'wp_cat_map_data', 'wp_cat_map_nonce' );
        $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $post_object['args']['post_meta'], true );
        printf( 
            '<label for="%s">%s</label>',
            $post_object['args']['label'],
            $post_object['args']['description']
        );
        printf(
            '<input type="text" id="%s" name="%s" value="%s"/>',
            $post_object['args']['label'],
            $post_object['args']['post_meta'],
            esc_attr( $value )
        );
    }

    /* NO CHECKS OR SECURITY WHATSOEVER, FOR DEBUGGING PURPOSES ONLY */
    public function save_post( $post_id, $post_object ) { 
        foreach( $this->metaboxes as $mbox ){
            if( isset( $_POST[ $mbox['post_meta'] ] ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $post_id, $mbox['post_meta'], $_POST[ $mbox['post_meta'] ] );
            }
        }
    }
}

$Code_Review_111019 = new Code_Review_111019(
    /* Screens */
    array( 'post', 'page', 'portfolio' ),
    /* Metaboxes */
    array(
        'map_lat' => array(
            'label' => 'wp_cat_map_lat',
            'title' => __( 'Add Latitude', 'wp_cat_map' ),
            'description' => __( 'Latitude', 'wp_cat_map' ),
            'name' => 'wp_cat_map_lat',
            'post_meta' => '_wp_cat_map_lat'
        ),
        'map_long' => array(
            'label' => 'wp_cat_map_long',
            'title' => __( 'Add Longitude', 'wp_cat_map' ),
            'description' => __( 'Longitude', 'wp_cat_map' ),
            'name' => 'wp_cat_map_long' ,
            'post_meta' => '_wp_cat_map_long'           
        ),
        'map_zoom' => array(
            'label' => 'wp_cat_map_zoom',
            'title' => __( 'Add Zoom', 'wp_cat_map' ),
            'description' => __( 'Zoom', 'wp_cat_map' ),
            'name' => 'wp_cat_map_zoom' ,
            'post_meta' => '_wp_cat_map_zoom'           
        )           
    )
);
```

---

**Suggestion:**
Instead of one Meta Box for each piece of information, I think it's better UX to have a single box for your plugin/feature and add the form fields there.

Comment: Thanks will try it out. As for the un-indented code that is because of the fact of the four space indenting that is required by the stackoverflow code highlighting

Comment: yep, I thought it could be a copy/paste issue, but then, imho, it would be nice to try to fix it in the Q...